# Pandas 'bar' chart groups DateTimeIndex entries, while standard plot doesn't

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, bar-chart

I can't wrap my head around the behaviour of pandas bar chart:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO("""Datetime;A;B;C
    2020-12-16 21:00:00;2;3;2
    2020-12-16 22:00:00;1;3;1
    2020-12-16 23:00:00;2;6;3
    2020-12-17 00:00:00;1;3;2
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";", index_col=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df.info()

print(df)

df.plot()
df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

results in:

[image]

As you can see, in the first chart the library retains four DateTimeIndex points that we have, whilst the bar representation is showing something different:

```
                     A  B  C
Datetime                    
2020-12-16 21:00:00  2  3  2
2020-12-16 22:00:00  1  3  1
2020-12-16 23:00:00  2  6  3
2020-12-17 00:00:00  1  3  2
```

My goal is to have four bars, where each corresponds to a record in the index (and where components of each stack are A, B and C).

Where does my misunderstanding lie?

- Windows 10
- Python 3.9.1
- pandas 1.2.0
- matplotlib 3.3.3

Comment: Not what I get, python 3.8.6, pandas 1.1.4 installed, I get all four bars correctly.

Comment: Thank you for checking, @PaulBrennan, I have Python 3.9.1 and pandas 1.2.0. I will try downgrading and see what happens!

Comment: @PaulBrennan, could you please let me know your matplotlib version? Assuming this is the (default) backend that you have used for the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulBrennan, we have identified that this is version-related. After downgrading to:

- Python 3.8.7
- Pandas 1.1.4
- Matplotlib 3.3.3

I get the expected behaviour:

[image]